# How to maintain the last index value in python list while doing iteration

Tags: python-3.x, iteration

My scenario is, lets say I have a
`list1= ["a","b","c"]` and this list is dynamic (data is getting appended).
My requirement is I need to process the list data each day to eventhub but I should not upload all data each day.I just need to upload the delta.

my approach is

```py
index=0
for i range(len(list1):
     ## upload
     index=index+1
```

I want to preserve the latest index value, for e.g. in first run index would be 2 and for next run index should be 3 not 0 as per above code. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply create a local file file that stores the index. Next time you need it load it and get from there on, assuming you are using the array and the script locally and only have to upload the part of that array.

```
import os

index = 0
if os.path.isfile("indexFile.txt"):
    f = open("indexFile.txt" , "r")
    s = f.read()
    f.close()
try: index = int(s)
except: index = 0

print("index is: " + str(index))
print("do something with that index")
index += 1
print("store the index back to file")
f = open("indexFile.txt" , "w")
f.write(str(index))
f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Is it possible to do without storing it in a file?

Comment: I you keep the script running forever, you may not need this. But otherwise you will have to store this information permanently. You can do this in the registry (windows) or in a database, or on a cloudstorage (it the provider offers that feature) or store it to a local file which is, as I think the simplest.